Apply ASAN option to a docker file
I am trying to Apply ASAN_OPTIONS=debug=true (for instance) when running a docker file using the command 'docker run ...'.
I have tried applying the address sanitizer options as "ASAN_OPTIONS=debug=true docker run ..." but when I run my application, I don't see any change in behavior from the address sanitizer. I am using a CMAKE build for a Linux environment.
Is there a different way this needs to be done in docker?
